# Using Auth0 Lock in popup mode

Tags: auth0

I am using Auth0 to implement social login with Google in my Ionic application.

I had set `redirect` option equal to `false` as per the [documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ionic/01-login) and this opens up a new tab.

Now when I set `redirect` equal to `true` (default) then as per the documentation it should display the login window in a popup, but I am getting the following error:

> Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=https://accounts.google….com%26from_login%3D1%26as%3D-13354ff19852788a&btmpl=authsub&scc=1&oauth=1' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'

I know because I am trying to open this inside `localhost`, that is why I am getting this error. But how can I test this feature in my local environment?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation on Auth0 Lock settings](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/customization#redirect-boolean-) if you set the `redirect` option to `false` (overriding the default of true) will trigger the use of popup mode.

> **redirect** - Defaults to true. When set to true, redirect mode will be used. If set to false, popup mode is chosen.

[Use of the popup mode](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/popup-mode) can result in a new tab or window to be opened while using the default redirect mode uses the current window to redirect to the identity provider.

The error you obtain when using `redirect=true` seems to indicate that you use iframes within your application and you're trying to perform the authentication from inside of an iframe. This is not supported by the Google identity provider as implied by the use of `X-Frame-Options: DENY` in the response from Google. (this header requests that the browser fails the navigation if it's within an iframe)

In conclusion, the error is not directly caused by Lock.

Comment: I don't want to use in-app browser to show login window to user. I want to display popup instead. How can I achieve this functionality than using Auth0

Comment: The trigger of the popup mode is achieved by using `redirect=false`. As stated in the docs this can lead to either a **new tab** or **window** to be opened; your problem is that it opens a new tab and not a window?

Comment: actually it opens up in a new tab, I want it to open up in a popup.

Comment: It's possible to adjust some characteristics of the window when using popup mode through the [`popupOptions`](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/customization#popupoptions-object-) setting. Does this satisfy your customization requirements?

Comment: @Bhushan Goel, just following up on this... did you get your problem solved?

Comment: no but currently I am able to login logout successfully, so I am concentrating on other functionalities for now. Can you suggest me some other plugin which I can use for social login with ionic ?

Comment: Not really, from a UX and simplicity perspective the recommendation would be Lock. You could use a more low-level library like [auth0.js](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js); it would give you more flexibility about how exactly you want things to happen, but will require more custom work.

Comment: Yes, I have also tried auth0.js but there was so much of custom work todo.